# exclude read-only files with rsync

Tags: rsync

While using rsync I would like to filter the files based on read/write attribute and potentially on timestamp.  The manual does not mention that this would be possible.  Well, is it?

In my shell I can do:

> dir *.[CHch](w)

to list all writable source C sources, so I hoped that:

> rsync -avzL --filter="+ */" --filter='+ *.[CHch](w)' --filter='- *' remote_host:dev ~/

might work, but apparently it does not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As of version 3.0.8, rsync doesn't support filtering on anything other than filename.

Your best bet is probably using `find` to generate the list of files to sync, and then using rsync's `--files-from` option.  `find` has most all the options you could ever want for differentiating files.